# Calling method and return

Tags: methods, return

"A `makeSound()` method that displays the message 'meow' onscreen when called"

```
public String makesound() {

return(System.out.println("meow"));
```

Is this correct?

Comment: what happens when you tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method should have a return type of `void` there is no need to return anything if your goal is to simply output a message to the console.

```
public void makeSound() { //note camel casing of method name
    System.out.println("meow");
}
```